# Using SQL to identify 1-to-1 records vs many-to-many

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm working in IBExpert modifying an existing query. Normally we run this query, export the results to Excel, then run a macro to create a new field - I'm trying to eliminate the step in Excel.

We have two key fields coming from different tables - let's call them ProjNo coming from Projects, and CustNo coming from Customers - which have a many-to-many relationship. One Project can involve multiple customers, and one Customer can have multiple projects running. There is a link table in between them to manage the relationship.

We want to be able to identify where there's a 1:1 correlation between these values, where a ProjNo appears only once and a CustNo appears only once. I've fumbled around quite a bit trying to put together a Case When statement, but I'm not having much luck. Here is my latest attempt:

```
(case when (select count(Proj.ProjNo) PCounts from Proj group by Proj.ProjNo)=1 and
           (select count(Cust.CustNo) CCounts from Cust group by Cust.CustNo)=1
      then "1:1" else "Multi" end) as Links
```

I know I'll need to include some kind of Where clause that only checks values that match the ProjNo in the main body of the query, but I'm not sure if I'm even in the right direction or how I would connect the SQL statements inside the Case to the main query.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was trickier than it has any right to be.  The three-table join made me want to join Cust and Link, and then Proj and Link, and then join those results.  The trick of it is that once you join one of the table pairs, you don't have to do it for the other pair, just link the last table into the linked pair.  Which sounds about as confusing as I found coding it to be.

So here's the three-way join I came up with.

```
SELECT cnc.cust_tot, pn_link.CustNo, pn_link.ProjNo, pn_link.proj_tot
FROM
    (SELECT CustNo, Count(CustNo) as  cust_tot
    FROM Cust 
    GROUP BY CustNo) as cnc
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT a.CustNo, a.ProjNo, b.proj_tot
    FROM
    Link as a 
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT ProjNo, Count(ProgNo) as proj_tot
        FROM Proj
        GROUP BY ProjNo) as b
    ON a.ProjNo = b.ProjNo) as pn_link
ON cnc.CustNo = pn_link.CustNo
WHERE cnc.cust_tot = 1
and pn_link.proj_tot = 1
```

At the end I have the `WHERE` statement to grab just the one-to-one matches.  To get the multi-matches just change it to

```
WHERE cnc.cust_tot > 1
or pn_link.proj_tot > 1
```

You can then `UNION` the two queries to get it all in one table again.  Whew.

Comment: Many thanks! I'll need to do a little modification to fit it in, but looks like it should get me what I need.